# Can a General Purpose Collection be Serialized?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, serialization, collections

If I have some Collection `Collection<SomeClass> classes;` can it be serialized as is? Or would I have to declare it as an ArrayList, HashSet, or some other concrete implementation that implements Serializable? If so what is the general practice for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `SomeClass` is serializable, any *standard* `java.util.collection` of `SomeClass` objects will be serializable.

I always assumed this was because the `Collection` interface itself extended `Serializable`, but - as you point out in your comment - this is not the case. So, I ran the following test:

```
public class Test {
    static final String filename = "d:/desktop/employee.txt";
    Collection makeColl(){
       return new ArrayList();
    }

    void writeColl(Collection c){ 
        try {
              ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("d:/desktop/employee.txt"));
              out.writeObject(c);
              out.close();
          } catch(IOException i){i.printStackTrace();}
    }

    Collection readColl(){
        Object that = null;
        try {
           ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
          that = in.readObject();
        } catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException i) { i.printStackTrace(); }
        return that;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    t.writeColl(t.makeColl());
    System.out.println(t.readColl().getClass()); 

  }
```

and what gets printed is: "class java.util.ArrayList"

So, what we can take from this is that, while the `Collection` interface does not extend `Serializable` directly (and indeed neither do `List`, `Set` or other sub-interfaces), all standard implementations of these interfaces *do*. Further, when you make a call to serialize an object that implements `Collection`, it will be serialized as an object of its concrete class (in the case of the above test, `ArrayList`). This, of course, is always the case when you serialize an object known only by an interface to the serializing method.

So, to answer your question (which is an interesting one): Technically, *no*, a `Collection` is not inherently serializable, and *yes*, one does need to be of a class that implements `Serializable` (either a standard implementation or a custom one) in order to be serialized. However, in practice, ***no, you do not need to cast a collection to an implementation in order to serialize it, because Java does this for you***.

To further clarify this: You can have a method that serializes arbitrary `Collection` implementations (such as the one in my example), and it will only cause a `NotSerializableException` in the case that a non-standard `Collection` implementation that *does not implement Serializable* is passed into it.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong about this, but the definition says otherwise: `public interface Collection<E extends Object> extends Iterable<E>`.

Comment: @SarahSzabo Not much there you can be wrong about :-|

Comment: @SarahSzabo No, you're not wrong. Please see my edit!

Answer (score 2):

All `Collection` implementations from the JDK are `Serializable`: Even though the `Collection` interface doesn't extend `Serializable`, all implementations (eg `ArrayList`, `HashSet`, etc) so implement `Serializable`.

Unless you are using special (your own or from a library) non-Serializable Collection classes,  and as long the class of the objects *in* the Collection (`SomeClass` in your example) are themselves `Serializable`, you don't need to worry.

Comment: +1 It's interesting that even the `AbstractCCC` classes don't implement `Serializable,` only the actual concrete implementations.